# Debugging nth-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following selectors:

```
.progress:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: teal;
}

.progress:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background: red;
}

.progress:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background: blue;
}
```

However all of the items end up with a teal background. Are these selectors correct? I'm thinking I should get:

1. Teal (every 3, starting with 1)
2. Red (every 3, starting with 2)
3. Blue (every 3, starting with 3)
   etc.

I've tested on Firefox 3.5.8 and Opera 10.10 on Ubuntu. Also tested with nothing but these rules in the CSS. I'm using the YUI Reset stylesheet but excluding it does nothing.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you are targeting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS seems to be correct, assuming the following HTML:

```
<div class="progress">1</div>
<div class="progress">2</div>
<div class="progress">3</div>
```

Perhaps you misunderstood the meaning of `:nth-child`, and your combination of HTML/CSS is incorrect.

`foo:nth-child` doesn't mean ‘every element that is the the *n*th child of `foo`’ but ‘every *n*th `foo` element’.

Pro tip: use [the `:nth-child()` tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/). Or this one: http://leaverou.me/demos/nth.html

Comment: @Ross: Like I said, there’s probably something wrong with your HTML. Here’s a working demo of the above example: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/cKr67/

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that each occurrence of `.progress` is actually the first child of an element. For your example to work, all `.progress` elements must be siblings.

i.e. this will work:

```
<div class="progress">1</div>
<div class="progress">2</div>
<div class="progress">3</div>
```

...but this won't:

```
<div><span class="progress">1</span></div>
<div><span class="progress">2</span></div>
<div><span class="progress">3</span></div>
```

In this case you'd need to move the `progress` class to the `<div>` then use this CSS:

```
.progress:nth-child(3n+1) span {
    background: teal;
}
```